# Discussão sobre a pergunta 'Quando e por que criar um aplicativo para dispositivo móvel?'

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

> EDIT: Eu mesmo votei pra fechar a pergunta. Depois da discussão com o
>   colega @JorgeB percebi que ela está suficientemente ampla a ponto de
>   dificultar a obtenção de respostas que sejam efetivamente úteis e
>   menos opinativas. Se conseguir pensar em uma forma de melhorá-la, eu
>   volto a insistir nesse conteúdo. :)

Estou abrindo aqui um tópico para a discussão da pergunta [Quando e por que criar um aplicativo para dispositivo móvel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73289/quando-e-por-que-criar-um-aplicativo-para-dispositivo-m%C3%B3vel), de minha autoria, apenas para evitar poluir demais a área de comentários por ali (que já está até ocorrendo - talvez eu devesse ter feito isso antes, desculpem).

A discussão ocorre em alguns pontos:

- Há quem argumente que a pergunta é ampla demais
- Há quem argumente que a pergunta é baseada em opiniões
- Há quem argumente que a pergunta é simplesmente fora do escopo porque assuntos atuais e inexplorados pertencem apenas à academia (entenda-se à Universidade)

Comment: Tanta coisa para ler Luiz ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Puxa, foi mals. :)

Comment: O maior problema desta pergunta é que eu só conheço uma pessoa no site que possa responder bem ela. O próprio AP :D Mas eu acho ela no geral boa, talvez tenha que ser melhorada, mas gostei dela.

Comment: @bigown "eu só conheço uma pessoa no site que possa responder bem ela" tchiiiiii

Answer (score 9):

### Um pouco de contexto

Já faz algum tempo que eu tenho essa dúvida. Em 2012, fui convidado a dar uma entrevista pelo Centro Universitário SENAC (onde sou professor) a respeito de "qual é o momento ideal para uma empresa migrar seu site para uma app?". E eu simplesmente não sabia a resposta! A matéria (de um jornal paulista menos popular e cujo nome eu sequer recordo) claramente explorava a tal "moda" de se produzir apps para toda e qualquer finalidade.

Hoje estamos em 2015, eu estudei um pouco mais sobre vários assuntos e tenho algumas informações que de certa forma me ajudam a formular uma opinião embasada. Mas ainda faltam alguns argumentos, que eu julguei que poderia obter aqui no SOPT. Por isso fiz a pergunta.

### O que eu acho sobre a pergunta

Eu tentei formular a pergunta da melhor forma que eu consegui para evitar de deixá-la ampla. A minha maior dificuldade foi na adição das tags, que eu acabei considerando apenas como mecanismo de busca (alguém interessado no assunto poderia chegar à pergunta pela busca naquelas tags). Ainda assim, na pergunta principal (em negrito no texto) eu coloquei "**[...] quais são os fatores (técnicos, financeiros, de UX, etc) [...]**" com certa preocupação, pois sabia que isso deixaria a pergunta mais ampla. Eu pensei em deixar apenas "quais são os fatores técnicos" ou "quais são os fatores de UX", mas imaginei que isso limitaria a pergunta e o seu interesse, e confesso que considerei que caso reclamassem da amplitude eu a editaria para deixá-la mais focada.

Eu admito que a pergunta, do jeito que está, é um tanto ampla (como eu disse, foi intencional), mas não acho que ela é ampla demais a ponto de não poder ser ao menos considerada como algo útil para a comunidade e eventualmente melhorada. Se julgarem que eu devo focar mais, posso editar de alguma forma similar à que eu havia planejado (sugestões são muito bem vindas!).

Por outro lado, eu discordo que ela é uma pergunta essencialmente baseada em opiniões. O fato de se tratar de algo com algum viés abstrato não limita as respostas apenas a conteúdos opinativos, como perguntas do tipo "qual é o melhor?" fazem. Por exemplo, não se costuma argumentar que perguntas sobre a forma ideal de modelar certo problema na Orientação a Objetos são opinativas, simplesmente porque se entende mais facilmente que é possível que os respondentes oferecam argumentos lógicos e bem fundamentados (baseados em experiência própria ou de outras pessoas, já bem aceitas pela comunidade nacional e/ou internacional, seja ou não documentado em livros e revistas).

De fato, essa é uma discussão antiga que ocorre todas as vezes que uma pergunta que não é essencialmente sobre programação aparece. Várias das perguntas da tag [ux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux), por exemplo, passaram por esse tipo de "provação" (peço perdão pela metáfora).

A respeito de ser algo atual e inexplorado, eu digo isso porque outra motivação para a criação da pergunta foi o fato de que uma empresa com que tenho contato está em processo de criar um aplicativo. Ao lhes oferecer consultoria de UX, eu percebi que o aplicativo por eles planejado simplesmente *não oferece* nada de novo ao que já é oferecido pelo sistema Web que eles tem. Não me refiro sequer ao fato do site da empresa não ser responsivo, mas essencialmente ao fato de que seus clientes simplesmente *não precisam* acessar o site (ou mesmo a app planejada) a partir do dispositivo móvel para executar as funções que usam atualmente.

Nesse caso, a minha visão é que se trata mesmo de "moda", e a empresa vai provavelmente ter um grande custo não apenas com o desenvolvimento da aplicação como também (potencialmente) com sua imagem: de uma empresa que fez um aplicativo inútil, que só ocupa espaço no aparelho do cliente. Esse tipo de análise, da "percepção" do cliente em relação à necessidade da app, é algo que eu posso fazer do ponto de vista de UX (e eu poderia também oferecer uma resposta baseada nisso lá na pergunta original - só não a fiz ainda porque queria ver antes a aceitação da pergunta pela comunidade). Mas eu sinto que há outros critérios que podem ser relevantes. O cache de dados e o acesso off-line, por exemplo, mencionados pelo colega @Piovezan em sua resposta, podem ser fatores relevantes mesmo quando uma aplicação Web é simplesmente "traduzida" para uma app mobile.

Assim, esse me parece um assunto atual que, por envolver necessidades comerciais, não é necessariamente tratado na academia. E mesmo que fosse, não vejo como isso nos impede de tratá-lo aqui também. O último argumento, de que isso não é escopo porque aqui não é a academia, é um tanto limitante e tacanho (sem querer ofender ninguém), pois a minha visão é de que o SOPT é uma ferramenta de construção colaborativa de conteúdo.

### Concluindo

Sim, eu acho que a pergunta é um tanto ampla. Não acho que eu sozinho consiga melhorá-la nesse aspecto (senão já o teria feito no momento da criação, hehehe). Mas acho que ela é relevante não só pra mim, como também para outras pessoas da comunidade (bom, ao menos também para os outro 7 indivíduos que votaram a favor) porque é um assunto atual que pode cair no seu colo a qualquer momento, quando a empresa em que você trabalha (ou pra quem presta consultoria) solicitar a criação de uma app relacionada aos serviços que eles já oferecem (não uma app para ser vendida na Apple Store ou no Google Play).

Por isso, peço ajuda. Se alguém souber como melhorá-la, por favor sugira uma forma de fazê-lo ao invés de simplesmente mencionar "fora do escopo!". Isso não quer dizer que a pergunta não deva ser fechada, se a comunidade assim julgar. Juro que não vejo problema algum nisso e também não me ofenderia. Talvez ela possa ser fechada para que uma nova, mais bem formulada, possa ser criada no futuro (até por outra pessoa) quando estivermos mais maduros sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 7):

Esta pergunta é bem ampla e bem baseada em opiniões, visto não termos um contexto concreto e poderem existir vários contextos.

Devias restringir a pergunta. Os motivos podem ser variados, como "rastrear o cliente", facilidade em manter os conteúdos perto do cliente (conteúdos *offline*), na aplicação ficam guardados, etc, etc ...

Há uma infinidade de motivos que podem levar a criar uma aplicação *mobile*. Tem de ser analisado caso a caso e isso acabará por criar muitas **opiniões** porque cada um passou por uma situação diferente para ter de fazer uma aplicação *mobile*.

Dei +1 por achar a pergunta muito interessante, mas votei para fechar porque realmente é **amplo demais**... Eu poderia-te dar 1001 motivos para fazer ou não a aplicação em 1001 contextos diferentes.

Se eu tenho um serviço WEB que faz X e quero que o meu cliente tenha acesso a Y será que devo fazer uma aplicação mobile ou o site responsivo serve? É essa a pergunta que poderá ser respondida neste caso.

Atenção que a pergunta é muito boa e atual e eu adorava discutir o assunto com todos, mas seria uma discussão sobre esse assunto e não uma resposta a uma pergunta.

Comment: Muito bem colocada a questão do contexto. De certa forma você ajudou a mudar um bocado a minha opinião a respeito da pergunta. :) Mas, ainda assim, você não acha que talvez seja possível uma resposta canônica com os motivos, de forma similar à que você colocou (rastreabilidade e conteúdo offline, sendo dois deles)? Realmente, o contexto é importante, mas será que a lista de motivações é assim tão grande que não possa ser elencada? Pensando um pouco aqui, mesmo os contextos variando muito talvez eles recaiam sobre as mesmas motivações em uma lista mais curta.

Comment: @LuizVieira é que para além dos contextos diferentes, basta as vezes mudar um variável para que já valha a pena fazer ou não a aplicação *mobile*. Eu estive a semana passada numa conferencia sobre aplicações mobile e cloud e não tens noção das variáveis que existem para fazer ou não fazer isto e aquilo...

Comment: Imagino que sejam muitas variáveis mesmo. Mas veja que o foco da minha pergunta é do ponto de vista da motivação de uso *por parte do usuário*, como motivador para a empresa investir esforço de criação. Afinal, de nada adianta o usuário ter uma app instalada em seu dispositivo se ele não a usa. Talvez isso não tenha ficado suficientemente claro na pergunta, mas eu acredito que limita bastante essa questão do contexto.

Comment: Há vários exemplos em que as mesmas motivações servem para fazer a aplicação e noutros casos para não a fazer. Entende?

Comment: Hum... não entendo. Consegue dar um exemplo de cada?

Comment: Para mim e a minha empresa pode ser bom fazer o rastreamento dos utilizadores por aplicação *mobile*, para a sua empresa pode ser bom fazer o rastreamento dos utilizadores por WEB. Por isso esse ponto (o rastreamento) pode ser usado em ambos os casos.

Comment: Desculpe insistir, mas é justamente esse o ponto. Como você mesmo menciona, é possível fazer rastreamento de uso por uma aplicação Web, e assim isso *não* é um argumento que por si só justifique o esforço de se criar uma app.

Comment: Olha a resposta que tiveste, muito opinativa e na verdade não está correta, porque nenhuma está. Porque **depende** de muitas coisas.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas. Obrigado pelo esforço em ajudar. :)

Comment: Pode ser, **depende** de que tipo de rastreamento você quer fazer... No caso da aplicação *mobile* ela pode informar a sua empresa de coisas sem mesmo o utilizador estar a mexer nela...

Comment: Entendo. Bom, obrigado mesmo pela sua visão. Ajudou um bocado. No final, acho que é realmente um assunto importante, mas difícil de ser tratado sem se tornar muito amplo. Vou continuar pensando a respeito e, se tiver alguma alternativa, eu editarei a pergunta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Boa parte da pergunta eu achei que formaria respostas baseadas em opiniões, mas o trecho que fala *fatores técnicos* eu não havia percebido:

> quais são os fatores (técnicos, financeiros, de UX, etc) que justificam a criação de um aplicativo para um negócio/empresa?

Neste caso eu acho que pode ser respondido e ao menos este trecho não é uma opinião, tanto que forneci uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73473/3635) destacando as diferenças entre página móvel e um aplicativo:

> A única vantagem de realmente desenvolver um aplicativo além ou no
>   lugar de um site mobile (ou responsivo) seria o fato dos navegadores
>   móveis terem mais limitações. As três características dos aplicativos
>   que podem tornar o desenvolvimento vantajoso são (eu acredito ser
>   apenas estas três):
>
> 1. Adicionar características customizadas que a maioria dos navegadores
>      móveis hoje não suportam, alguns exemplos:
>
>    - Tirar uma foto e mandar diretamente pro aplicativo, sem a necessidade
>        de selecionar na galeria.
>    - Gravar áudio e subir diretamente para o
>        aplicativo
> 2. Coletar dados do cliente com maior facilidade e com menor
>      risco de perda para direcionar "propaganda" ou "produtos" destinados
>      ao perfil do cliente (sim as empresas fazem isto)
> 3. "Manter logado" (evitar que tenha que digitar a senha toda vez que
>      abrir o navegador) ou permitir múltiplos contas logadas, esta
>      característica apesar de um pouco incomum pode ser eventualmente
>      necessária.

Então levando em consideração a comparação de *sites móveis vs aplicativos*, acho que ao menos está parte pode justificar manter a pergunta aberta.

Talvez ela seja *ampla demais*, por falar de vários pontos, mas o trecho que citei pode ser aproveitado, se editar a pergunta e colocar o foco nesta questão das limitações do navegadores móveis ou criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Dá sempre para responder, mas não deixa de ser ampla demais. Você próprio se contradiz "no meu ponto de vista" e "Opinião pessoal"... Isso é baseada em opiniões.

Comment: @JorgeB. Apenas uma parte é opinião pessoal, como eu disse o ponto "sites móveis vs aplicativos" pode ser respondido e "mas o trecho que citei pode ser aproveitado". Ou seja a parte de comparar os sites móveis com aplicativos é algo pode ser respondido e não é opiniativo, pois existem realmente limitações impostas nos navegadores mobiles, mas apenas esta parte. "Opinião pessoal" se refere aos outros trechos da pergunta, o qual eu havia respondido antes da última edição: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/73473/4

Comment: Guilherme, eu agradeço novamente pelo esforço continuado. Mas cada vez que alguém responde eu entendo mais o ponto dos colegas com o @JorgeB. A pergunta é relevante, mas ela é simplesmente difícil de ser respondida. A sua edição melhorou a sua resposta, trouxe alguns pontos interessantes, como acesso a recursos multimídia, canal para interação mais direta, controle mais seguro da interação (não precisa fazer login continuamente). Mas isso só comprova o que o colega Jorge disse: depende fortemente do contexto. continua...

Comment: A nova resposta de outro colega Junior, por exemplo, tem alguns aspectos que podem ser verdade, mas da forma como estão colocados acabam sendo apenas afirmações dogmáticas e, infelizmente, opinativas. De fato, não sei mais o quanto realmente essa pergunta pode ajudar outras pessoas de forma realmente prática. Não pretendo excluí-la, mas acho que seria bom fechá-la para evitar que novas respostas com "mais do mesmo" apareçam.

Comment: É amplo demais e por isso é que acaba por ser opinativo. Só isso @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @LuizVieira Entendo, mas me pareceu que a pergunta falava algo como qual a justificativa para criar criar um "site móvel x aplicativo", ao meu ponto de vista são as limitações e isto que eu tentei passar e isto torna a sua pergunta útil sim, no entanto se o site móvel puder atender a todas necessidades, então neste caso qualquer opinião pode ser considerada opinião. Ao meu ver a sua pergunta é sim útil, desde que coloquemos em foco o que o aplicativo pode fazer que um site móvel não pode :) Espero que pense nisto.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas não foi o que eu disse: *Talvez ela seja ampla demais, por falar de vários pontos, mas o trecho que citei pode ser aproveitado.*? O trecho pode ser aproveitado, talvez se ele refizer a pergunta ou criar uma nova. Realmente talvez eu deva deletar a resposta, mas irei faze-lo apenas se talvez surgir uma pergunta o qual o foco seja as limitações dos navegadores mobile :) -- Espero que entenda.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu concordo que ela é de interesse. Só não sei, da forma como está indo, vai ser efetivamente útil. A sua resposta não é ruim, mas há algumas coisas que eu acho que podem ser discutíveis, e isso vai demandar muito esforço de ambos (seu e meu). Não é muito pra isso que o SOPT serve, entende? A ideia era sermos capazes de colocar respostas lá que fossem, de alguma forma, auto-suficientes.

Comment: @LuizVieira mas foi o que eu quis dizer (Talvez ela seja ampla demais, por falar de vários pontos, mas o trecho que citei pode ser aproveitado), talvez eu não tenha conseguido me expressar, quero dizer que podemos aproveitar o trecho das limitações e talvez você reformular a pergunta ou postar uma nova, focada somente nisto, assim acredito que ela não seria ampla, pois as respostas seriam apenas sobre as limitações das tecnologias. O que acha?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Você tem alguma sugestão sobre como eu poderia editar a pergunta?

Comment: @LuizVieira vou pensar em algo :) -- Assim que possivel lhe respondo, obrigado

Comment: @LuizVieira te juro que esforcei a minha menta ao maximo :( -- Só consegui pensar em algo como: *Quais características um aplicativo pode ter que o site móvel não pode ter?* -- Eu sei que não ficou grande coisa, mas prometo pensar em algo mais :) Obrigado pela consideração

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento hehe É, eu sei como é difícil. Obrigado pela ajuda! A sua sugestão é bacana, mas é outra pergunta. Digo, não é *exatamente* o que me interessa/preocupa (o meu foco é um tanto funcional, e do ponto de vista do usuário). Mas é igualmente interessante, e você mesmo pode postá-la como uma outra pergunta, se assim desejar.

Comment: Espero que o meu ponto de vista sobre o numero de usuário móveis ajude em alguma consideração. @LuizVieira

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ajudou sim.